# Symfony 4 - Unable to transform value for property path "[myDateTime]": Expected a \DateTimeInterface

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I want to render a datetime picker using Symfony forms.

Since the datetime picker requires just an input text (because it returns a simple string) I've decided to use the form DataTransformers to transform data from datetime to string and viceversa.
But when I try to render my page I get the following error message:

> Unable to transform value for property path "[myDateTime]": Expected a \DateTimeInterface.

My Controller class is the following:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\DateTimeToStringTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class HomeController
 * @package App\Controller
 */
class HomeController extends Controller
{    
    /**
     * @Route("/test", name="form_test")
     */
    public function testForm(Request $request)
    {
        $data = ['myDateTime' => new \DateTime()];
        $builder = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
            ->add('myDateTime', DateTimeType::class, ['label' => 'My datetime']);

        $builder
            ->get('myDateTime')
            ->addModelTransformer(new DateTimeToStringTransformer(null, null, 'd/m/Y H:i'));

        $form = $builder->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dump($form->getData());
        }

        return $this->render('test.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

My view template is so simple:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <button class="btn btn-success">{{ button_label|default('Send') }}</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

To render my datetime picker I've used form themes stored in form/fields.html.twig:

```
{% use "bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig" %}

{% block datetime_row %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_help(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block datetime_widget %}
    <div class="input-group date" id="{{ id }}" data-target-input="nearest">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#{{ id }}" {% if value %}value="{{ value|e('html_attr') }}"{% endif %}/>
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#{{ id }}" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock datetime_widget %}
```

And added this theme into twig.yaml config file:

```
twig:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig'
        - 'form/fields.html.twig'
```

Does anyone help me to understand why that does not work or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: DateTime field excpect DateTime value:       $builder = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
            ->add('myDateTime', DateTimeType::class, ['label' => 'My datetime']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have your form working properly you have to use `TextType` instead of `DateTimeType` for your `myDateTime` field:

```
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
        ->add('myDateTime', TextType::class, ['label' => 'My datetime']);
```

Explanation:

Symfony by default adds a `ViewTransformer` of type `DataTransformerChain` for `DateTimeType` fields. This transformer is called inside `normToView` function in `Form` class and expects an argument of `\DateTime` class. However by adding the ModelTransformer of type `DateTimeToStringTransformer` you have already changed the normalized value of `myDateTime` field to a string and that's why you get the error.

Furthermore, your code won't work even if you use

`->addViewTransformer(new DateTimeToStringTransformer(null, null, 'd/m/Y H:i'));`

instead of

`->addModelTransformer(new DateTimeToStringTransformer(null, null, 'd/m/Y H:i'));`

because in this case the `DataTransformerChain` transformer is called before the transformer you added and you will get the same error, this time from the `DateTimeToStringTransformer`.

Comment: I disagree with your suggestion to use a TextType. Why not just remove the transformer completely and use the Symfony DateTime form type as it's intended to be used?

Comment: Also he could technically get this to work by setting the input to a string, but again... Why? Just use it the way it was intended.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but my response was referring to the specific problem that the OP had, so I explained how he could get his code as he has it. Personally, I don't find any reason not to just use DateTimeType

Comment: From php code I need to use DateTime object and not a simple string. By setting the DateTimeType input field to string I will get a string as input.
Your solution works well for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked for me, thank you! I don't get, why some Symfony components are so difficult for solving trivial tasks... just why?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `DateTimeToStringTransformer`. Remove this Transformer. By default the Symfony `DateTimeType` expects a `\DateTime` object.

So what's happening is your transformer is transforming it to a string and then the `DateTimeType` is expecting a `DateTime` but it is getting a string so it's causing this error.

You can read more here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#input